# htaccess site/category/name/page error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url in my site with pagination, like this:

```
http://localhost/category/food/1

category = to call category.php
food = is ONE category, may have any name
1 = is the page number
```

The problem is, maybe I have page number, maybe not. If I don't have a page number I want just to send page 1 to php.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) /category.php?categoria=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*) /category.php?categoria=$1&id=$1
```

To sum up, I want to access my page in two different ways:

```
http://localhost/category/food - in this case send 1 to php
or
http://localhost/category/food/1
```

what is wrong in my code that it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules as this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Avoid using `.*` as it matches everything in regex.